# HttpContext.Request["x"] throws exception

Tags: c#, system.web

I have the following code throws exception (absolute path required):

```
string versionIdStr = HttpContext.Current.Request["xxx"];
```

Is Request["xxx"] read-only?  How do I set it?

Comment: The error and the code do not match. Are you sure this is the line that is throwing the exception? Are you sure there is no file manipulation code that is doing this?

Comment: What is the particular exception type you are seeing?

Comment: Where are you calling this ASP.NET will throw an exception if you try to use this property when the HttpRequest object is not available, i.e. Application_Start method of the Global.asax

Comment: @JGinSD - The OP posted the exception message.

Comment: No, it does not: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpContext.Request.get'". What's the real code?

Comment: The exception is of type      ArgumentException

Comment: The real code is `string versionIdStr = HttpContext.Request[JetConstant.XDOC_PARAM_XSN_URI];` where the value is what i posted above.

Comment: No, that's not the real code. You can't use `HttpContext.Request` at all. Do you maybe mean `HttpContext.Current.Request`?

Comment: Yes, it should be `HttpContext.Current.Request`.  I forgot it was returned by some other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out: problems with SimpleWorkerRequest.  I didn't set a physical path, and the query shouldn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Request[xxx]
```

Seek Path =

```
querystring -> form -> cookie -> session variables
```

I believe it falls in the last argument

try to be more specific

e.g.

```
HttpContext.Request.Form[...]
HttpContext.Request.QueryString[...]
...
```